# Как проверить есть ли елемент в блоке уже или нет на js

Tags: javascript

Делает функция такое, добавляет информацию из дива, на каком был клик. Берет все необходимые данные из блока, и формирует другой див, и добавляет в другое окно по клику. Вопрос такой, как сделать проверку, есть ли тот див, что сформировал в окне (том, что добавил);

```
function addBakets() {
       let thisCardProduct = this.closest('.cardProduct');
       let weith = thisCardProduct.querySelector('.weith').textContent;
       let amount = thisCardProduct.querySelector('.amount').textContent;
       let divCountPrice = thisCardProduct.querySelector('.countPrice').outerHTML;
       let img = thisCardProduct.querySelector('img').src;
       let textNameProduct = thisCardProduct.querySelector('h3').textContent;
    
    
       let text = `<div class="orderBot" id="lolka">
    <div class="cardOrder">
       <img src="${img}" alt="">
       <div class="descripOrder">
          <h4>${textNameProduct} </h4>
          <div>
             <span class="amount">${amount}</span>/
             <span>${weith}</span>
          ${divCountPrice}
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>`;
    
       newBacket.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", text)
     
    }

bakets.forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListener('click', addBakets)
});
```

Comment: ты можешь получить из контейнера элемент с нужным id и если такого нет получишь `null`

Comment: Можно посмотреть на chield элементы

Comment: @Grundy Так смотри, у меня есть 30 карточок, и я не буду им ставить разные ID будет долго, а если у меня будет 300 карточок то будет еще хуже, а в окно будет добавлятся как раз все эти карточки при клике, то как мне сделать?

Comment: не понял твой комментарий. ты устанавливаешь класс и id. если ты их не хочешь ставить как ты будешь различать элементы, которые хочешь проверить на одинаковость?

Comment: @Grundy ну да , ид поставить и проверять, а єсли таких елементов будет 200 - 1000? и че ставить каждое другое ИД?

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo, непонятно про что ты говоришь. Попробуй словами сформулировать что именно ты хочешь сделать. Как проверить наличие одного элемента внутри другого - в комментарии выше

Comment: Grundy Cмотри) , есть в магазине много карточок с товарами, например 200, и когда ты нажимаешь на карточку(с продуктом) то добавляет в корзину, и єсли еще раз нажать на карточку чтоб добавить в корзину, то проверка делается, если есть в корзине такая карточка, то не надо добавлять, иначе добавлять. Теперь как то понятнее стало?) если ж будет на странице таких 200 карточок, че добавлять ид? не очень ж хорошо так)

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo, почему? лучше конечно класс, но не принципиально. Класс вполне может генерироваться при выводе, то есть руками ничего не надо прописывать. В любом случае тебе надо как-то определять похожесть карточек, почему не сделать это по простому?

Comment: @Grundy а эсли проверять по картинке src .Такое коректно?

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo, а какая разница? Если у тебя и так есть и класс и картинка?